# Audio uploaded from iOS not playing on android and vice versa

Tags: android, swift, audio, android-mediaplayer, mediarecorder

I am building a chat app in which users can upload audio too on Firebase Storage. But the audios uploaded from android are only playable on android and the audios uploaded from iOS are only playable on iOS. On the Android side, I am getting this exception while playing iOS audio:

**java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1**

This is the code I am using to upload audio from the android side:

```
private void startRecording() {
    try {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "AroundEU_media_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,
                ".3gp",
                storageDir
        );

        fileName = image.getAbsolutePath();

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Recording_Tag", "prepare() failed");
        }

        recorder.start();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void stopRecording() {
    try {
        if (recorder!=null){
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();
            recorder = null;

            uploadAudio();

        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tap and hold to record !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

And the code for playing audio on android side is :

```
try {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(messageModelList.get(position).getAudio());
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setDataSource(context, uri);
    player.prepare();
    player.start();
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

I have searched a lot but could not find a proper solution. So please help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you playing the audio from URL or from local storage?

Comment: I am playing audio from url

Comment: I have answered it below!

Comment: It’s probably related to the audio encoding of the file. Can you tell what file types are being stored?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be playing the audio from a URL. For playing audio from a URL it takes some time to prepare but you playing that immediately that causing the problem. You need to prepare it asynchronously and play it when it's prepared.

Here's an example of how to do it.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(player -> {

    player.start();

});

try {

    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(/*Audio Url*/);
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

} catch (Exception exception) {

    Timber.d("Error -> %s", exception.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: The audios uploaded from android side are playing fine but the audios from iOS are not playing, This solution did not work for me

Comment: I think then you need to have audio files generated in the same format from both android and iOS sides to make it work!

Comment: Add some more info in your question about how you're generating it on the iOS side.